# How to mock require('uuid/v1') correctly with Sinon

Tags: javascript, mocking, sinon

`schema.js`:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
.......
const sessionId = uuid.v1();
```

`schema.test.js`:

```
const uuid = sinon.mock(require('uuid'));
.......
uuid.expects('v1').returns('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
```

The above works perfectly and `sessionId` gets the value of `0000.....`.

However, the `schema.js` file actually looks like this:

```
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
.......
const sessionId = uuidv1();
```

How should `schema.test.js` be so that the `sessionId` gets the value of `0000.....`?

```
const mockUuid = sinon.mock(require('uuid/v1'));
........
mockUuid.returns('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
```

returns `TypeError: mockUuid.returns is not a function`.

```
const mockUuid = sinon.mock(require('uuid/v1'));
........
mockUuid.expects().returns('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');
```

also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and simply refactored the code to make it easier to test. I just changed the import from `const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');` to be `const uuid = require('uuid');` and changed the places where it was called in the code from `let newUuid = uuidv1();` to `let uuid.v1();`

That allowed me to do the unit testing as in your first paragraph. Part of writing tests is refactoring code to make it easier to test, so I didn't feel there was a problem with this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately require('uuid') is deprecated and will be removed post-v3 https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid